# RestKit with cocoapod with use_frameworks! can't use AFNetworkReachability

Tags: afnetworking, restkit, cocoapods, ios-frameworks, xcode7-beta5

My pod file looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'RestKit'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
```

On top of my App delegate I added:

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
```

In the *application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* I added this:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSString class]];
```

So far it compiles fine, then I added:

```
AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"asdf"]];
```

Again, works fine, then I tried the reachability:

```
[client setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock: ^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status)
     {
         NSLog(@"Reachability status changed");
     }];
```

Unfortunately, this fails to compile and gives the following error:

> no visible @interface for 'AFHTTPClient' declares the selector
>   'setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:'

I went to check why that might be, and found that the compilation of this method is guarded by `_SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H` macro, which for some reason resolves to false in this case.
I tried to link my project against the SystemConfiguration framework, but it doesn't help. My assumption is that the RestKit should be linked with it at compile time, and when I checked the RestKit pod, the SystemConfiguration is indeed present in the Link Binary with Libraries phase. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Xcode7b5, cocoapods 0.38.2
Sample project can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27427137/test1.zip).

Comment: Running into the same problem. Solved it yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not, just didn't use the Accessibility in the project.